# Action is called but didn't executed in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I was trying to build login application. Its working fine but on refresh all the states are lost. When I log in the application [ from login page ] a token is received from backend, i store that token locally and  calls the action "loadUser" which ultimately gets the user info and stores it. I was planning to use same action whenever my page is reloaded. Since my Navbar page is common to all the pages so i created was using useEffect hook to call loadUser action from there itself.

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import logo from "../../resources/images/desi-hip-hop.png";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { userActions } from "../../state/actions";
import LogoutGoogle from "../auth/LogoutGoogle";
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.user.isAuthenticated);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      dispatch(userActions.loadUser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while loading user call");
    }
  }, []);
```

From here i am exporting my action which is being used in navBar to call the action.
[image]

```
//Will store logged in or Signed up user
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("load User is called");
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/auth");
    console.log("loading user with value" + res);
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    console.log("loading user  completed");
  } catch (error) {
    //TODO
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.msg,
    });
  }
};
```

the following action i.e. loadUser works fine when called from other actions but not when we are refreshing window. It shows following behavior while debugging.

1. My useEffect is called

[image]

2. It reaches till here but doesn't go inside the code
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:)

In `useEffect` you should provide as argument to `dispatch` function, that takes `dispatch` as an argument and does some logic.

You are providing function `userActions.loadUser`, that returns another function. This returned function is never executed.

Simply change `dispatch(userActions.loadUser)` to `dispatch(userActions.loadUser())` and everything should work

Comment: Thank you so much. { Now time to cry in corner for making this silly mistake }.